# A pythonic (3) way to declare more than one variable on a line

Tags: python

I ran across some code in GitHub https://github.com/OeslleLucena/FASNet

It threw a syntax error at this line:

```
# dimensions of images. (less than 224x 224)
img_width, img_height = (,)
```

It looks like the code is trying to declare multiple variables on the same line. I see them get passed as parameters later on. I am assuming this code worked at some point but I haven't seen this convention used before. Is it a python 2 thing? Are they empty tuples? How would you do this properly in Python 3? TIA

Comment: It seems like they were trying to do something like this: `img_width, img_height = (None, None)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of code is a syntax error in both Python2 and Python3. Perhaps the code is meant to be changed? For example

```
a, b = (10, 20)
```

initializes two variables `a` and `b` with values `10` and `20` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Moberg's answer, in Python3 you can declare an element and a list in one line with the operator *.

```
head, *queue = range(5)
```

It initializes two variables `head` and `queue` with values `0` and `[1, 2, 3, 4]` respectively.